# Why doesn't $v_{max} = \omega A$ work for this pendulum problem?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, velocity

I have a pendulum of length $L$ swinging with some angle $\theta$ and period $T$. I want to find the maximum velocity (which occurs at the bottom of the motion). I am using two methods that give me different answers.

First, conservation of energy:

$$ \frac{1}{2}mv_{max}^2 = mgL(1-\cos\theta)$$

Using $T = 2\pi \sqrt{L/g}$, I get:

$$ v_{max} = \sqrt{2gL(1-\cos\theta)} = \frac{T}{2\pi}g\sqrt{2(1-\cos\theta))}$$.

However, I also know that $v_{max} = \omega A$, where the amplitude $A$ is $L(1-\cos\theta)$, which gives

$$ v_{max} = \frac{T}{2 \pi}g(1-\cos\theta)$$

Why do these methods disagree? I believe the first answer is correct, but I am not sure why the second answer is incorrect. If $v_{max} = \omega A$ is the problem, under what circumstances does $v_{max} = \omega A$ break down?

Comment: My friend $T=2π \sqrt{L/g}$ is only for very small oscillations it will not be valid everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second equation is not correct. The amplitude refers to the motion along the arc, $A=L\theta$, or horizontally, $A=sin(\theta)$. These will all agree for small theta converging to $v_{max}=(T/2\pi)g\theta$. 
  For large amplitudes the system is nonlinear and the motion is not simple harmonic motion (sinusoidal), so $v_{max}=\omega A$ does not apply.

Answer (score 2):

For small $\theta$, $\cos \theta \approx 1-\theta^2/2$.

$v_{\rm max} = \dfrac{T}{2\pi}g\sqrt{2(1-\cos\theta))}\approx \dfrac {Tg\theta}{2\pi}$ and with $A \approx L\theta,\, v_{\rm max} \approx \dfrac{2\pi}{T}L\theta \approx \dfrac {Tg\theta}{2\pi}$.